# Does Emacs support font-lock for Ruby 2.0 percent literals?

Tags: ruby, emacs, font-lock

How can I fix ruby 2.0 symbol array syntax in Emacs?

In standard `ruby-mode`, it displays symbol arrays in default color. In `enh-ruby-mode`, a definition of symbol array breaks my color theme entirely.

Comment: What did you try? Please give us a context.

Comment: For example i have clean emacs 24.3 installation, and enh-ruby-mode installed. ruby-mode looks like this http://s30.postimg.org/6cigclv5t/ruby_mode.png and enh-ruby-mode looks like this http://s22.postimg.org/x5atup4wh/enh_ruby_mode.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ruby-mode` is currently not capable of rendering the array syntax correctly.

If you really are concerned about that, consider using the [`highlight-escape-sequences`](https://github.com/dgutov/highlight-escape-sequences) package, available through [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/).

**Edit** The same author (Dmitry Gutov) seems to have made a commit on `ruby-mode`, fixing the syntax-highlighting for array of symbols, as we can see [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-diffs/2013-07/msg00176.html). But that change is not available yet, so I *guess* we need to wait for Emacs 24.4...

Comment: Thanks!!! I've googled a lot, but i haven't found anything useful about this issue.

Comment: I don't think `highlight-escape-sequences` does anything relevant to this question. Speaking of Emacs 24.4, there was some support added so that people can include tricky characters there, but as far as highlighting goes, it looks like a string literal, which is not accurate (ideally it should look like three blue-ish words inside white parens, in the default theme, that is).